# Hydrogen atom: Estimation of binding energy from each force

Tags: forces, atomic-physics, hydrogen, binding-energy

I've been asked to give an estimation on the binding energy related to each fundamental force (gravitational, electromagnetic, weak and strong) for the Hydrogen atom (you know, the one with a single proton and a single electron).

Now, both the electromagnetic and gravitational ones are easy to compute, since they must be the energy that would imply to take the electron away from the proton until $r \rightarrow \infty$. This is, the electromagnetic and gravitational potential energy of the system.

However, things get messy when I try to solve for the other two: As far as I know, strong force binds nucleons together, but theres only one to bind here so... I don't see where could that be acting. Regarding weak interaction... Well, my knowledge on it is pretty weak (pun intended), but again, as far as I know, it just doesn't appear in the Hydrogen atom, does it?

I've tried computing the mass defect for the system proton-electron, but using $9.10938 \times 10^{-31}$ kg for the electron mass, $1.6726219 \times 10^{-27}$ kg for the proton mass and $1.6735575 \times 10^{-27}$ kg for the Hydrogen atom mass, I don't get a satisfying result.

Can anybody give me a hint on where should I be looking to? Thanks!

Comment: How do you go about estimating the gravitational binding energy and where do you get stuck ?

Comment: There is no strong nuclear force between electron and proton. The mass defect for electron bound to nucleus is much smaller than for a nucleus. This is why in chemistry they consider mass conserved in chemical reactions.

Comment: kilograms.....?

Comment: Hmmmm... 13.7eV for Coulomb, 0.0000000000 for everything else...

Comment: @JonCuster $Z_0$'s are in atoms (e.g. parity violation, also electron capture for $W$'s), the question is ...how do you get a binding energy?